# OpenERP7 Add a field to contacts

Tags: python, odoo

I'm trying to make a custom module which requires a boolean field to be added in the contact window.

To be more specific, in the "Sales" tab under the menu "Customers", then you select a customer and then under the tab "Contacts". When you select a contact a window opens where it shows you some information about the contact. I would like to add a boolean field there.

So there's a python file in the custom module where I've added the column:

```
class res_partner(osv.osv):
_inherit = 'res.partner'
_columns = {
    'x_invoice_partner': fields.boolean('Invoice partner',
                                        help="Select this if you want to send invoices to this person"),
}
```

Now I only need to add the field to the xml in order for it to show up but I'm not sure how to setup the xml since this is a window that comes from an action.

Any help would be much appreciated, thanks in advance

Comment: I think that the contact window as you said is not `res.partner` object! check it again first then we can help you with the view! I am using `openerp 6` and that view belongs to `res.partner.job`